# Why can't I see android button text?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In the graphical layout I do see a button but no text on the button.
I dont see the button text in the graphical layout but in the emulator I do see it. Not sure whats going on.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCurrentUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.23"
            android:text="@string/logOut"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure, but if it shows up on the emulator why does it matter? The preview is for very basic testing.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio? Any themes in your app?

Comment: Eclipse. Yes there are themes I believe Im using a template for a lot of this.

Comment: Try cleaning the project. In Eclipse, project -> clean... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as others said don't know what's going but if it shows on emulator you're ok

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your AndroidManifest.xml doesn't conflict with your layout xml graphical trial changes. My Android says App theme but I was using their graphical layout to generate code text and they conflicted...so for a day I saw nothing. There are also cross-platform differences and lots of code requires higher api versions so they don't mix either. These could be theoretically correct but will stop it in its tracks. And yes, rebuild.